# How can I extract a major and minor version number from the end of a string?

Tags: regex, perl, extract

I'm trying to extract the CMS Tikiwiki version, but I have a problem extracting the version.
I'm able to extract only the first part of the number, example:

Version 15.0, I can extract only 15, but I want to extract 15.0.

```
if ($res=~ m/as of version (.+?)\./) {

  $version = $1;

 }
```

Sentences to extract version

> The following list attempts to gather the copyright holders for Tiki as of version 15.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
if ($res =~ m/as of version (\d+(?:\.\d+))\./) {
```

If this is the end of the string you may want,

```
if ($res =~ m/as of version (\d+(?:\.\d+))\.$/) {
```

The pattern `(\d+(?:\.\d+))` captures any digit followed by an optional grouping of `.` and one or more digits.

Comment: I would put `[\d.]*` instead of `(?:\.\d+)`

Comment: @TLP that would match `as of version 5......`

Comment: The strictness of the regex is matched to the given string. If the string should change, the regex must change as well. This is loose enough to match any given string with the given format.

Comment: the question was to match it to the given string, it's even in an if statement so it only matches when it provides the output the OP is looking for. He's setting a variable called `$version`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```perl
/as of version (.+)\./
```

but I would be tempted to use

```perl
/as of version (\S+)\./
```

`\S` matches non-space characters.

---

By the way,

```perl
my $version
if ( $res =~ /.../ ) {
   $version = $1;
}
```

can be written as

```perl
my ( $version ) = $res =~ /.../;
```

Comment: Unlike Evan Carroll's solution, this version won't fail if they start using `15.0.1`. It's also simpler.

Comment: ... or throw in other things like `15.0-TRIAL` :)